# Console Read with array[]

Tags: c#

```
Console.WriteLine("\n\n\t\tWhat is your option?\n\n\t\t  ");
            index = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (index)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.Clear();
                    System.Console.WriteLine("\n\n\tHOW MANY ID'S FOR STUDENTS\n\n\t\t");
                    ids = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    for (i=0; i < ids; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\n\tPRESS 'u' FOR U.G. students,\n\n\t'm' FOR ONLY MASTERS and\n\n\t 'p' FOR ONLY PHD STUDENTS\n\n\t\t");
                        c[i] = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
                        if (c[i] == 'u')
                        {
                            Console.Clear();
                            u[i].inputu(); //ug input
                        }
```

Hey guys i'm having a little problem with this part of code when i want to read c[i], i tried to use Char.Parse(Console.Readline()); but didnt work :(

Comment: `Console.ReadLine` returns `string` not `char`. You can assign it in a string then you can use it's index like; `string s = Console.Readline(); if(s[i] == 'u') { }` And I don't think you need to use `Char.Parse` because since `String` class implements `IEnumerable<char>` all `c[i]` will be `char`.

Comment: @SonerGönül so what should i do to read that c[i] cause it really needs to come to the next part "If"

Comment: @SonerGönül Tks i got it ^_^ it works

Comment: You are quite welcome `;)`

Answer (score 0):

try this code hope it will well help

```
Console.WriteLine("\n\n\t\tWhat is your option?\n\n\t\t  ");
        index = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        switch (index)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.Clear();
                System.Console.WriteLine("\n\n\tHOW MANY ID'S FOR STUDENTS\n\n\t\t");
                ids = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                for (i=0; i < ids; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\n\tPRESS 'u' FOR U.G. students,\n\n\t'm' FOR ONLY MASTERS and\n\n\t 'p' FOR ONLY PHD STUDENTS\n\n\t\t");
                    c[i] = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine()); 
                    if (c[i] == 'u')
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        u[i].inputu(); //ug input
                    }
```

Comment: it said "Property or indexer 'string.this[int]' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only " :(

Comment: c[i] the one with = Convert.Tochar(Console.Readline());

Comment: i think this isn't an array `c[i]`. try to declare like this `char[]c=new char[10];`

Comment: thank you,i Figured out where is the problem ^^, i just need to change c = Console.ReadLine(); then C[i] can work